# Manage Redux state with React navigation goBack() function

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm learning `React Native` and `Redux` and I've started using 3rd party libraries - specifically `React Navigation`.

I have two screens, `Main Screen` and `Alarm Setup Screen`.
The `Main Screen` has a list of Alarms and the `Alarm Setup Screen` has the details of the alarm and offers the possibility to edit its details (hour, repeat, enable, etc).
I have a button on the `Main Screen` to create a new Alarm. When the user presses the button, the user is redirected to `Alarm Setup Screen` and have to possibility to create a new alarm. The new alarm has already all the parameters filled by default and it's added to redux state.
I also have two buttons on the `Alarm Setup Screen` (`Save` and `Cancel`).
If the user presses the `Cancel` button I delete the newly alarm created and I use the `goBack()` function from `React Navigation`.

The problem is when the user presses the `Cancel` button after he presses the create new alarm button on the `Main Screen`. 
If I delete the newly created alarm from `Redux` state, I get an error because the screen tries to render and the alarm is not there anymore. This happens because the state is changed before the `goBack()` function is triggered.

```
cancelAlarmEditButton() {
  const alarmToDelete = this.props.alarmSetup.deleteNewAlarm;
  const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
  goBack();
  this.props.dispatchDeleteCurrentAlarmState(alarmToDelete.id);
```

}

Because I couldn't find a way to solve this problem, I tried to update the `Redux` State on the `Main Screen`. This works without any error, but the list of alarms is not updated when I delete the alarm.

```
checkAlarmToDelete() {
  const alarmToDelete = this.props.alarmSetup.deleteNewAlarm;
  if (alarmToDelete && alarmToDelete.delete) {
    this.props.dispatchDeleteCurrentAlarmState(alarmToDelete.id);
  }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.checkAlarmToDelete();
}
```

If I update the `Redux` state in the `Alarm Setup Screen` I get an error. If 
I update in the `Main Screen` the state is not the correct.

```
//Reducer code:
case DELETE_ALARM: {
      const {id} = action.payload;
      const alarmsData = state.alarmsData.filter(val => val !== id)
      const mergedState = state.merge({
        deleteNewAlarm: undefined,
        alarmsData: {
          [id]: undefined,
        },
      }, { deep: true })

      return saveState(mergedState)

      return state;
```

Basically, I want to know the best way to manage `Redux` state and `React Navigation` using the `goBack()` function.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you add your action and reducer code here?

Comment: @Cool7 I edited my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just manage to solve my problem.
Before I update the redux state I just change the render function to return an empty View.

```
cancelAlarmEditButton() {
  const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;
  const {alarmId, newAlarm} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
  if (newAlarm) {
    this.render = () => {
      return (<View/>)
    }
    this.props.dispatchDeleteCurrentAlarmState(alarmId);
  }
  goBack();
}
```

This way there is not problem if the alarm object is not there anymore.